# App not compatible with buildpack - Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

Имеется простейший эхобот на Питоне, работает и запускается с PyCharm.
Проблема в деплое на Heroku, у меня в папке находятся скрипт, файл с конфигом для скрипта, runtime.txt с поддерживаемым 3.7.2

1. Скрипт
2. Файл конфига для скрипта
3. `runtime.txt` с поддерживаемым 3.7.2 Питоном
4. `requirements.txt`, сделанный через `pip install -r requirements.txt`
5. `procfile`, содержащий `worker: python bot.py` (bot.py - тело скрипта, ссылается на config.py, где лежит токен бота в тг)
6. `.gitignore`
7. `.git`

Есть 2 варианта развития событий, либо я просто пытаюсь задеплоить приложение через `git push heroku master` и получаю ошибку

```
 !     No default language could be detected for this app.
            HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed
```

Если же я установлю  билдпак Питона, например, через сайт и страницу своего приложения в настройках, то появится иная ошибка:

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

Вроде все делаю по инструкции Heroku, но, видимо, где-то ошибаюсь, подскажите, в чем.

Comment: Разве Хероку не только для node.js?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/
Судя по заглавной странице и пакетам для разных языков, то нет @Qwertiy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ошибку, необходимо было добавить `Procfile`, `requirements.txt` и `runtime.txt` в репозиторий через `git commit`

А `Procfile` надо было установить не в папку репозитория, а в корневую папку(D:\Procfile, например), тк Хероку видит файл только если он в корневой папке